# How to call different function when toggling on and off in ion-toggle

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ion-toggle

When Toggle button is "on"  see below the function `buttonOn()` is called,
                                 [image: pic1]

I want to call `buttonOff()` when toggling it "off" as below

[image]

**.html**

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="buttonOn()"></ion-toggle>
```

**.ts**

```
buttonOn() { 
    // this function is called;
}

buttonOff() {
   // how to call this function when toggle button gets off?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `ngModel` to bind your toggle's status, then call the function depends on the status

**.html**

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="status" (ionChange)="onChange()"></ion-toggle>
```

**.ts**

```
status=true;
onChange(){
  if(this.status){
    this.buttonOn();
  }
  else{
    this.buttonOff()
  }
}

buttonOn() { 
    // this function is called;
}

buttonOff() {
   // how to call this function when toggle button gets off?
}
```